# How to use use es6 classes in a VUE js app so that methods and data are bound to a class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm lookin for a better sulution to use ES6 classes in a VUE JS app.
I tried using es6 classes for my vue js app.

```
class App {
    constructor(components) {
        this.el = "#app";
        this.data = {
            dialog : new Dialog()
        };

        this.watch = {
            "watcher": function (val) {
            }
        };

        this.methods = {
            get(){
                console.log('get');
            }
        }
    }
}

class Dialog {
    constructor(components) {
        this.title = "";
        this.content = "";
    }
}

var app = new Vue(new App());
```

Methods and data are not part of the class.
I am looking for a solution where it is posible to bind the data directly as properties and use the methods as you would do within a JS class.

```
class App {
    constructor(components) {
        this.dialog = new Dialog();
    };

    get(){
         console.log('get');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for https://class-component.vuejs.org/ ?

Comment: It does look promising. However it does require typescript.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Just because there's a typescript guide doesn't mean you require typescript

Comment: It does use the @Component decotator. I'm pretty sure that can't be used in plain javascript.

Comment: It requires TypeScript *or* Babel https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#manual-setup